# MX records to ensure failure of email delivery

Tags: domain-name-system, email-server, mx-record

I'm managing a set of domain names that used to have `MX` records pointing to a hosted mail service.
When the hosted email service was deactivated, emails sent to the (now invalid) addresses resulted in *mailer daemon* failure messages, which was ok.

This not the case anymore.

Now the domain names have been migrated on new name servers, and I have setup new `A` records but no `MX` records, as they won't be associated to new mail boxes.

The problem is that now, if someone sends an email to one of the old addresses, no error is reported to the sender even though the messages get lost. I guess that's because there are valid `A` records in place.

What's the best way to ensure that a *mailer daemon* error is generated? Should I setup `MX` records pointing to an invalid IP (e.g. localhost)?

### update

As @MichaelHampton said in the comments, I did receive *failure messages* after a few days. Different mail providers (custom IMAP/SMTP, gmail, yahoo) use different retry strategies and error reporting, but the mail delivery **will** fail and the senders should receive the *failure messages* (although I imagine that it depends on the sender's mail provider).

Comment: If the sender didn't get an error, the message went somewhere. I will bet you that it is not lost, but is queued up on one of your servers.

Comment: ok. That's what I imagined. Is it because it's _following_ the `A` records? How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: The problem is that the servers referenced by the `A` records should NOT handle emails.

Comment: In that case, reconfigure or remove their mail servers. Easy.

Comment: There are no mail servers already. Could you be more explicit, please?

Comment: If that's the case, then senders _will_ get bounces. It might take three or five days though.

Comment: Hi @MichaelHampton, you were right, thank you. I started receiving _delivery failure_ messages after a few days. Each SMTP (or provider, eg gmail or yahoo) has a different retry policy.

Comment: I've updated the question with this new piece of information, for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways you can configure DNS that will make delivery impossible, but some of them will be considered to be a temporary error and cause the SMTP layer to retry for several days before sending an error back.

If you want to get an error message back to the sender right away, the most reliable approach is to direct them to a server that does talk some SMTP. Giving success on the `HELO` and `MAIL` commands followed by a permanent error on the `RCPT` command is the way to make it absolutely clear to the sender, that the address is not valid.